# I write a main and register class when Im running the app and pressing the register button app is crashing saing: app keeps stoping ,no showing erorr

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im started with login and registraion want to run the register activity by pressing the register button but its keep crashing and closing the app.

the main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Set the title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Firebase App");

       /* //Open login activity
        Button buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,LoginActivity.class );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); */

        //Open Register Activity
        Button buttonRegister = findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,RegisterActivity.class );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

the Register class:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextRegisterFullName  , editTextRegisterEmail , editTextRegisterDoB ,
            editTextRegisterMobile , editTextRegisterPwd , editTextRegisterConfirmPwd;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private RadioGroup radioGroupRegisterGander;
    private RadioButton radioButtonRegisterGanderSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You can register now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        editTextRegisterFullName = findViewById(R.id.editText_register_full_name);
        editTextRegisterEmail = findViewById(R.id.editText_register_email);
        editTextRegisterDoB = findViewById(R.id.editText_register_dob);
        editTextRegisterMobile = findViewById(R.id.editText_register_mobile);
        editTextRegisterPwd = findViewById(R.id.editText_register_password);
        editTextRegisterConfirmPwd= findViewById(R.id.editText_register_confirm_password);

        //RadioButton for Gander
        radioGroupRegisterGander = findViewById(R.id.radio_group_register_gender);
        radioGroupRegisterGander.clearCheck();

        Button buttonRegister = findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedGanderId = radioGroupRegisterGander.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioButtonRegisterGanderSelected = findViewById(selectedGanderId);

                //Obtain the entered data (EditText to string)
                String textFullName = editTextRegisterFullName.getText().toString();
                String textEmail = editTextRegisterEmail.getText().toString();
                String textDoB = editTextRegisterDoB.getText().toString();
                String textMobile = editTextRegisterMobile.getText().toString();
                String textPwd = editTextRegisterPwd.getText().toString();
                String textConfirmPwd = editTextRegisterConfirmPwd.getText().toString();
                String textGander; //Can't obtain yet

                // Empty check
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textFullName)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please enter your full name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterFullName.setError("Full Name is required");
                    editTextRegisterFullName.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textEmail)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please enter your Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterEmail.setError("Email is required");
                    editTextRegisterEmail.requestFocus();
                } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(textEmail).matches()) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please re-enter your Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterEmail.setError("Valid Email is required");
                    editTextRegisterEmail.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textDoB)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please enter your Date of Birth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterDoB.setError("Date of Birth is required");
                    editTextRegisterDoB.requestFocus();
                } else if (radioGroupRegisterGander.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Pleas select your gender", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        radioButtonRegisterGanderSelected.setError("Gender is required");
                    radioButtonRegisterGanderSelected.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textMobile)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please enter your mobile no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterMobile.setError("Mobile No. is required");
                    editTextRegisterMobile.requestFocus();
                } else if (textMobile.length() != 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please re-enter your mobile no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterMobile.setError("Mobile No. should be 10 digits");
                    editTextRegisterMobile.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textPwd)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterPwd.setError("Password is required");
                    editTextRegisterPwd.requestFocus();
                } else if (textPwd.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password should be at least 6 digits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterPwd.setError("Password too weak");
                    editTextRegisterPwd.requestFocus();
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textConfirmPwd)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please confirm your Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterConfirmPwd.setError("Password confirmation is required");
                    editTextRegisterConfirmPwd.requestFocus();
                } else if (!textPwd.equals(textConfirmPwd)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Pleas enter the same password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editTextRegisterConfirmPwd.setError("Password confirmation is required ");
                    editTextRegisterConfirmPwd.requestFocus();
                    //Clear the entered passwords
                    editTextRegisterPwd.clearComposingText();                        editTextRegisterConfirmPwd.clearComposingText();
                } else {
                    textGander = radioButtonRegisterGanderSelected.getText().toString();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                        registerUser(textFullName,textEmail,textDoB,textGander,textMobile,textPwd);
                }
            }
        });    
    }
    //Register User using the credentials given
    private void registerUser(String textFullName, String textEmail, String textDoB, String textGander, String textMobile, String textPwd)
    {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textEmail , textPwd).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User registered successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser =auth.getCurrentUser();    
                    //send Verification Email
                    firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();

                   /*//open profile after successful registration
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,UserProfilActivity.class);

                    //to prevent user from returning back to register activity on pressing back button after registration
                    intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish(); // to close Register Activity*/       
                }
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

there is no error icon in the top right corner and i dont know where and how i can find the problem or where they are located.

cheked my manifast its all right.

Comment: if it crashes, there is very likely to be an error somewhere. do you have log files

Comment: you maen logcat?

Comment: any logs. they can be printed to a console, to .log files, ....

Comment: there is so much going on in my logcat i understand nothing from it...

Comment: so, when you say "there is no errors", what you mean is: "I have no idea whether there are errors or not"? Those logs are your best chance of figuring out what went wrong

Comment: Is the red lines in my logcat with a capital E letter are my errors?

Comment: I see ,
what i ment is that there is no erros icons in the right top corner....

Comment: logcat is just plain text. Do you not know how to spot errors in logs? Do you have any error handling? do you see any stacktraces?

Comment: When you get that message there is ALWAYS an error in logcat.  YOu're just not finding it

Comment: honstly i have no experience in android studio and I dont know how to locate my erros .

Comment: Run your app with the logcat opened. Now, as soon as you press the register button, a lot of logs in redcolor will start appearing in logcat. You should check which logs were generated as a result of you pressing the register button. Then paste them here